# Bash скрипт добавление нового сайта. Проблема с проверкой условий

Tags: bash, if

Всем привет. Решил написать небольшой скрипт на автоматическое прописывание нового сайта в лампе и столкнулся в проблеме модуля проверки.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Добавление сайта в систему

clear
echo "Введите название сайта"
read p1
echo '\n'
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/$p1 && sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/$p1 && sudo find /var/www/$p1 -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \; 

echo "<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@$p1
    ServerName $p1
    ServerAlias www.$p1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/$p1
    ErrorLog \${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog \${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/sites-available/$p1.conf > /dev/null


echo "127.0.0.1 $p1" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts > /dev/null
echo '\n'

var=$(sudo a2ensite $p1.conf)
c="Enabling site $p1. To activate the new configuration, you need to run: systemctl reload apache2"
if [[ "$var" == "$c" ]]; then
    echo "Верно" 
else 
    echo "Не верно" 
fi
```

в конце скрипт должен проверять вывод команды sudo a2ensite $p1.conf и если вывод равен значению переменной с  то все гуд. Я уже выводил и эхом значения для проверки и засовывал в файл для просмотра. Значения для нового сайта идентичны с переменной с. Пытался ограничить двоеточие в тексте  но результата не дало.

нашел для себя пару решений

```
var=$(sudo a2ensite $p1.conf) > 123.txt  
if grep -q "Enabling site $p1. To activate the new configuration, you need to run: systemctl reload apache2" 123.txt; then
```

здесь просто загоняю вывод в файл и беру с него инфу

или

```
if [[ "$var" == *"To activate the new configuration, you need to run":""* ]]; then
```

Поиск по части фразы.

Пытался полную фразу ввести но после двоеточия начинаются проблемы

также делал через $?

Как по мне это костыль и хочется разобраться с первым вариантом. Почему идет не корректное сравнение переменных.

Comment: P.S. Стоит последняя убунта с поднятой лампой

Comment: Вот это `#!/bin/sh` немного смущает. Для начала попробуйте в конце скрипта сделать вывод: `echo "$var"; echo "$c"` и убедиться что они (не)совпадают.

Comment: Добрый день. По поводу #!/bin/sh - да, запускаю код через sudo bash. По поводу вывода - выше писал, что проверял и эхом и записью в файл. Причем если сравнивать из записи в файле по средством grep, то все ок